# Is there an option to limit the presented axis values in a ggplot with significance label without cutting them off in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, ggpubr

I'm analyzing numeric data with values between 1 to 7. I want to plot boxplots and show the significance across categories. My problem is that adding the labels also extends the values in the y axis. This might imply that the possible data range is up to more than 7 - which is not the best. I tried using ylim() but using it cuts off the signif labels. Is there a way to make the axis values to be 1-7, without cutting the information the should apear beyond this range?

my current plot:

[image: current plot]

when using ylim()

[image: using ylim()]

the desired outcome is something like that:

[image]

Comment: set the `breaks` and `limits`

Comment: ... or perhaps only the `breaks`.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! thank you both :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution is setting breaks:
gboxplot(...)+ scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 7, by = 1))